# Formula to Calculate Subscriber Churn Revenue

Tags: excel, math, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to sum up 12 months of subscriber revenue factoring a 6% monthly churn (assuming no signups) to come up with the one-year value of a subscriber. A simple future value gives me the start and end values, but I'm looking to get the *sum* of the monthly declining revenues in a single Excel / Google Sheets formula. I can make 11 entries (plus the starting month full value), but is there a better one-liner or formula for this?

This gives me the 12th-month revenue:

```
=FV(-6%,11,0,100)
```

I'd like to get the sum without this:

```
=100 + FV(-6%,1,0,100) + FV(-6%,2,0,100) ... FV(-6%,11,0,100)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the sum of a finite geometric series:

`1 + r + r^2 + r^3 .... + r^11`

And the [sum of this series is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)

`(1 - r^12) / (1 - r)`

where `r = 1 - 6%`

So the formula would be

`= (1 - (1-6%)^12 ) / (1 - (1-6%) ) * 100`

---

This is assuming the OP meant

```
=100 + FV(-6%,1,0,-100) + FV(-6%,2,0,-100) ... FV(-6%,11,0,-100)
```

as `FV(-6%,1,0,100)` would output a negative number

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks! And yes - my intention was to have FV output a positive number. My bad on not including the negative on the present value.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about such math but would the following formula give you the result?

```
=100+SUMPRODUCT(FV(-6%,ROW(1:11),0,-100))
```

The formula works in both Excel and Google Spreadsheets

Comment: This would require me to list out the FVs though, no? I'm looking to do this with just a starting value and X number of months.

Comment: Very cool use of `Row()`! But I would suggest using `-100` inside the FV formula?

Comment: @[I'm Joe Too](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2458149/im-joe-too): No, it won't need you to list out the FVs because `row(1:11)` merely lists the numbers 1 through11 and does not use the values in those rows. You could substitute `row(1:11)` with `column(A:K)` and get the same result.

Comment: So I really wish I could accept two answers here. This one from JvdV is the perfect Google Sheets/Excel one-line formula but I figured that out after I read, used, and accepted @ADW's explanation and formula. Thanks to both of you!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @ADW. Like I said, I don't know much about this math :)